# embed external link to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to embed external link to my anchor tag with javascript.

When i press on achor tag, which is actually an image, i want to load < iframe > with that external link.

Firstly i need iframe to be hidden and only show when the anchor tag is clicked.

This is what i have so far:

**html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="openUrl();"><iframe name="myIframe" height="600" width="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>"<img src="img/icon.png"></a>
```

**js**

```
function openUrl(){
    var myUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zBFGkUmVkAs";
    document.getElementsByName('myIframe')[0].src = myUrl;
}
```

});

But it doesn't work

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: An `iframe` won't load when its `src` is set, if it at the same time is displayed `none`. Is it?

Comment: an iframe cannot be a descendant of an <a> element

Comment: You actually have a typo here, where you used a capital `F` for `myIFrame` in your function but not in your `name` attribute

Comment: @LGSon just a copy-paste mistake. not in the code

Comment: As it works with the posted code when I changed that, it means there is more code we haven't seen yet. If you want a proper answer, provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue you described.

Comment: @aiden87 try this https://jsfiddle.net/sajankumarv/p7z38rhq/8/

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan this actually works yes!. hopefully i can code this into modal window because now it ruins everything on my page

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan you should add comment, so i can mark your answer

Comment: @aiden87 I have commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aiden87 
Try this code below, I have made a demo please check this link.     https://jsfiddle.net/saujankmarv/p7z38rhq/8/

html:

```
<a href="#" id="atag">
<img src="img/icon.png">
  <iframe style="display:none;" id="myFrame"></iframe>
</a>
```

js

```
var  openUrl = function() {
console.log('log');
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zBFGkUmVkAs";
iframe.style.display = "block";
}
document.getElementById('atag').addEventListener('click', openUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  function openUrl() {
            var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
            iframe.style.display = "block";
            iframe.attr('src' , 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/zBFGkUmVkAs');
            }

 <a href="#" onclick="openUrl();">
   <img src="img/icon.png">
 </a> 
 <iframe width="560" height="315" id="myFrame"  frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen style="display:none">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: hey! some1 above already posted a solution. though i am trying to fit it into modal window - modal body now

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function openUrl() {
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
iframe.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openUrl();"><img src="img/icon.png"></a>
<iframe width="560" height="315" id="myFrame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zBFGkUmVkAs" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) :(

Comment: Check it out. Don't check using code snippet. Make a html file on your device and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Inline click handlers are not the best solution , you can hide the iframe initially and then toggle its visibility.

```js
$('a').on('click' , function(){
 $(this).find('iframe').attr('src' , 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/zBFGkUmVkAs');
        $(this).find('iframe').slideToggle(0);
 return false;
})
```

```css
a > iframe {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><iframe name="myIframe" height="600" width="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>"<img src="https://zartnerds.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/thumbnail.png"></a>
```